# How to make these curves on left and right side of the container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Anybody had an idea how to make curves on the left side and right side of a rounded container like in the picture above in flutter?

have been trying for hours but still can't make it looks like the shape in the picture

[image]

Right now i'm using svg image and stack to make it looks like the image above, but i don't really want to use svg but real hard coded widget (using container and else), Here is my current code snippet:

```html
Widget get _promoButtonView {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/images/promo_frame.svg',
            width: AppQuery.instance.width,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: AppSpacer.instance.edgeInsets.symmetric(x: 'standard'),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/coupon.svg'),
                    AppSpacer.instance.vWsm,
                    AppText.label(
                      AppCopy.instance.tr('input_cashback_code'),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const Icon(Icons.chevron_right)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you include your current snippet

Comment: if you are using that card shape image, that will also work, or you can use ShapeBorder/OutlineBorder on Container shape

Answer (score 0):

As per the design, it seems like you have to use CustomPainter. If you have mentioned image in svg format, you can use [fluttershapmaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) to get the CustomPainter code, just you have to add svg image there and you will get code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).